# Where is ProviderBase in .NET 5?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

We have many projects based on the provider model/pattern. (Reading files from various sources, create reports from various sources, etc.) I have been unable to find anything equivalent to the ProviderBase in .net 5. We need an abstract interface/class that can be configured at runtime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect ProviderBase is something we will never see in ASP.NET 5 and beyond. Configuration is simpler in 5, and dependency injection is prevalent. Now you can create a class implementing your own custom interface and not have forced inheritance from ProviderBase. You can register the class or an instance of the class with a container and it will appear throughout the application. It might look like a bit more work at first, but I also suspect embracing DI will result in less code, and simpler code.